Permissions issues in Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
Ubuntu noob here,
Was messing around with permissions and external disk mounting options and I think I made a mistake with the permissions. Now I can't install updates and the gnome-desktop won't start. I've tried rebooting to no avail.
I couldn't figure out how to make this display properly here so apologies, let me know if there's a better way.
jellyadmin@jellyfin-drake:~$ systemctl start gdm.service
==== AUTHENTICATING FOR org.freedesktop.systemd1.manage-units ===
Authentication is required to start 'gdm.service'.
Authenticating as: jellyadmin
Password: 
==== AUTHENTICATION COMPLETE ===
Job for gdm.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status gdm.service" and "journalctl -xeu gdm.service" for details.
jellyadmin@jellyfin-drake:~$ systemctl status gdm.service
× gdm.service - GNOME Display Manager
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/gdm.service; static)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2024-06-11 14:32:31 EDT; 18s ago
    Process: 4615 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/gdm/generate-config (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
        CPU: 7ms

Jun 11 14:32:31 jellyfin-drake systemd[1]: gdm.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Jun 11 14:32:31 jellyfin-drake systemd[1]: Stopped GNOME Display Manager.
Jun 11 14:32:31 jellyfin-drake systemd[1]: gdm.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Jun 11 14:32:31 jellyfin-drake systemd[1]: gdm.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jun 11 14:32:31 jellyfin-drake systemd[1]: Failed to start GNOME Display Manager.
Jun 11 14:32:31 jellyfin-drake systemd[1]: gdm.service: Triggering OnFailure= dependencies.
jellyadmin@jellyfin-drake:~$ 
jellyadmin@jellyfin-drake:~$ 
jellyadmin@jellyfin-drake:~$ systemctl start displaymanager.target
==== AUTHENTICATING FOR org.freedesktop.systemd1.manage-units ===
Authentication is required to start 'displaymanager.target'.
Authenticating as: jellyadmin
Password: 
==== AUTHENTICATION COMPLETE ===
Failed to start displaymanager.target: Unit displaymanager.target not found.
jellyadmin@jellyfin-drake:~$ 
jellyadmin@jellyfin-drake:~$ 
jellyadmin@jellyfin-drake:~$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3
debconf: DbDriver "templatedb": could not write /var/cache/debconf/templates.dat-new: Read-only file system
jellyadmin@jellyfin-drake:~$ 
jellyadmin@jellyfin-drake:~$ 
jellyadmin@jellyfin-drake:~$ cd /
jellyadmin@jellyfin-drake:/$ ls
bin  boot  cdrom  dev  etc  home  lib  lib32  lib64  libx32  lost+found  media  mnt  opt  proc  root  run  sbin  snap  srv  swap.img  sys  tmp  usr  var
jellyadmin@jellyfin-drake:/$ ls -l
total 4194384
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root       root                7 Aug  9  2023 bin -> usr/bin
drwxr-xr-x   4 root       root             4096 Jun  7 06:51 boot
dr-xr-xr-x   2 root       root             4096 Aug 10  2023 cdrom
drwxr-xr-x  20 root       root             4700 Jun 11 14:00 dev
drwxr-xr-x 156 root       root            12288 Jun 11 06:33 etc
drwxr-xr-x   3 root       root             4096 Feb  4 20:28 home
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root       root                7 Aug  9  2023 lib -> usr/lib
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root       root                9 Aug  9  2023 lib32 -> usr/lib32
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root       root                9 Aug  9  2023 lib64 -> usr/lib64
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root       root               10 Aug  9  2023 libx32 -> usr/libx32
drwx------   2 root       root            16384 Feb  4 20:24 lost+found
drwxrwxr-x   5 jellyadmin jellyadmin       4096 Feb 20 09:50 media
drwxr-xr-x  11 jellyadmin root             4096 Jun 10 13:47 mnt
drwxr-xr-x   4 root       root             4096 Feb 10 15:12 opt
dr-xr-xr-x 210 root       root                0 Jun 11 14:00 proc
drwx------   8 root       root             4096 Feb 10 15:08 root
drwxr-xr-x  42 root       root             1200 Jun 11 14:23 run
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root       root                8 Aug  9  2023 sbin -> usr/sbin
drwxr-xr-x  17 root       root             4096 Feb  5 19:05 snap
drwxr-xr-x   2 root       root             4096 Aug  9  2023 srv
-rw-------   1 root       root       4294967296 Feb  4 20:25 swap.img
dr-xr-xr-x  13 root       root                0 Jun 11 14:00 sys
drwxrwxrwt   8 root       root             4096 Jun 11 12:12 tmp
drwxr-xr-x  14 root       root             4096 May 30 10:48 usr
drwxr-xr-x  14 root       root             4096 Feb  4 20:46 var
jellyadmin@jellyfin-drake:/$ 

As suggested:
jellyadmin@jellyfin-drake:~$ systemctl status gdm.service
× gdm.service - GNOME Display Manager
 Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/gdm.service; static)
 Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2024-06-11 14:32:31 EDT; 2h 36min ago
Process: 4615 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/gdm/generate-config (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
    CPU: 7ms

Jun 11 14:32:31 jellyfin-drake systemd[1]: gdm.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Jun 11 14:32:31 jellyfin-drake systemd[1]: Stopped GNOME Display Manager.
Jun 11 14:32:31 jellyfin-drake systemd[1]: gdm.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Jun 11 14:32:31 jellyfin-drake systemd[1]: gdm.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jun 11 14:32:31 jellyfin-drake systemd[1]: Failed to start GNOME Display Manager.
Jun 11 14:32:31 jellyfin-drake systemd[1]: gdm.service: Triggering OnFailure= dependencies.
jellyadmin@jellyfin-drake:~$ 

And:
jellyadmin@jellyfin-drake:~$ journalctl -xeu gdm.service
░░ The job identifier is 6945.
Jun 11 14:32:30 jellyfin-drake generate-config[4618]: error: Failed to create file “/var/lib/gdm3/greeter-dconf-defaults.013GP2”: Read-only file system
Jun 11 14:32:30 jellyfin-drake systemd[1]: gdm.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
░░ Subject: Unit process exited
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
░░ 
░░ An ExecStartPre= process belonging to unit gdm.service has exited.
░░ 
░░ The process' exit code is 'exited' and its exit status is 1.
Jun 11 14:32:30 jellyfin-drake systemd[1]: gdm.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
░░ Subject: Unit failed
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
░░ 
░░ The unit gdm.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'exit-code'.
Jun 11 14:32:30 jellyfin-drake systemd[1]: Failed to start GNOME Display Manager.
░░ Subject: A start job for unit gdm.service has failed
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
░░ 
░░ A start job for unit gdm.service has finished with a failure.
░░ 
░░ The job identifier is 6945 and the job result is failed.
Jun 11 14:32:31 jellyfin-drake systemd[1]: gdm.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
░░ Subject: Automatic restarting of a unit has been scheduled
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
░░ 
░░ Automatic restarting of the unit gdm.service has been scheduled, as the result for
░░ the configured Restart= setting for the unit.
Jun 11 14:32:31 jellyfin-drake systemd[1]: Stopped GNOME Display Manager.
░░ Subject: A stop job for unit gdm.service has finished
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
░░ 
░░ A stop job for unit gdm.service has finished.
░░ 
░░ The job identifier is 7077 and the job result is done.
Jun 11 14:32:31 jellyfin-drake systemd[1]: gdm.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Jun 11 14:32:31 jellyfin-drake systemd[1]: gdm.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
░░ Subject: Unit failed
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
░░ 
░░ The unit gdm.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'exit-code'.
Jun 11 14:32:31 jellyfin-drake systemd[1]: Failed to start GNOME Display Manager.
░░ Subject: A start job for unit gdm.service has failed
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
░░ 
░░ A start job for unit gdm.service has finished with a failure.
░░ 
░░ The job identifier is 7077 and the job result is failed.
Jun 11 14:32:31 jellyfin-drake systemd[1]: gdm.service: Triggering OnFailure= dependencies.
lines 1286-1340/1340 (END)

Then:
jellyadmin@jellyfin-drake:~$ findmnt -T /var/lib/gdm3
TARGET SOURCE    FSTYPE OPTIONS
/      /dev/sda2 ext4   ro,relatime

Here's my fstab file:
jellyadmin@jellyfin-drake:/etc$ cat fstab
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda2 during curtin installation
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during curtin installation
/swap.img   none    swap    sw  0   0
/dev/disk/by-uuid/8CD8-C307 /mnt/8CD8-C307 auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
/dev/disk/by-label/WD_BLACK     /media/jellyadmin/WD_BLACK auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
/dev/disk/by-label/SG_GREEN     /media/jellyadmin/SG_GREEN auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
/dev/disk/by-label/EFI /mnt/EFI auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
/dev/disk/by-label/SG_Green_2     /media//jellyadmin/SG_Green_2 auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
/dev/disk/by-label/EFI /mnt/EFI auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0

check current mounted drives:
jellyadmin@jellyfin-drake:/var/snap/firefox/common/host-hunspell$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs           1.6G  9.5M  1.6G   1% /run
/dev/sda2       915G   44G  826G   5% /
tmpfs           7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
/dev/sda1       1.1G  6.1M  1.1G   1% /mnt/8CD8-C307
tmpfs           1.6G   64K  1.6G   1% /run/user/1000

And here is what I get when trying to remount the internal drive:
jellyadmin@jellyfin-drake:/dev$ sudo mount -o remount,uid=1000,gid=1000,rw /dev/sda2
mount: /var/snap/firefox/common/host-hunspell: mount point not mounted or bad option.

So I try unmounting and remounting to no avail:
jellyadmin@jellyfin-drake:/$ umount /dev/sda2
umount: /var/snap/firefox/common/host-hunspell: must be superuser to unmount.
jellyadmin@jellyfin-drake:/$ sudo umount /dev/sda2
jellyadmin@jellyfin-drake:/$ 
jellyadmin@jellyfin-drake:/$ 
jellyadmin@jellyfin-drake:/$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs           1.6G  9.5M  1.6G   1% /run
/dev/sda2       915G   44G  826G   5% /
tmpfs           7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
/dev/sda1       1.1G  6.1M  1.1G   1% /mnt/8CD8-C307
tmpfs           1.6G   64K  1.6G   1% /run/user/1000


jellyadmin@jellyfin-drake:/$ sudo mount -o remount,uid=1000,gid=1000,rw /dev/sda2
mount: /: mount point not mounted or bad option.

After a fresh install of Ubuntu Server 24.04 LTS, and using the "Disks" app to set only my 3 external drives to auto mount:
jellyadmin@jellyfin-drake:/etc$ df -h
Filesystem                         Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs                              1.6G  2.0M  1.6G   1% /run
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv   98G   14G   80G  15% /
tmpfs                              7.8G  4.0K  7.8G   1%     /dev/shm
tmpfs                              5.0M   12K  5.0M   1%     /run/lock
/dev/sda2                          2.0G  103M  1.7G   6% /boot
/dev/sda1                          1.1G  6.2M  1.1G   1%     /boot/efi
tmpfs                              1.6G  100K  1.6G   1%     /run/user/124
tmpfs                              1.6G  136K  1.6G   1%     /run/user/1000
/dev/sdb1                          1.9T  1.8T   64G  97%     /media/jellyadmin/WD_BLACK
/dev/sdc2                          3.7T  3.5T  185G  96%     /media/jellyadmin/SG_GREEN
/dev/sdd2                          3.7T  812G  2.9T  22%     /media/jellyadmin/SG_Green_2
jellyadmin@jellyfin-drake:/etc$ 

And:
jellyadmin@jellyfin-drake:/etc$ cat fstab
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv during curtin installation
/dev/disk/by-id/dm-uuid-LVM-oOin7c1pI9TWy5aSmyLAJJrNcbiq5Oc1yziartSobMNQQW253V5MUwFaP0zIuXu7 / ext4 defaults 0 1
# /boot was on /dev/sda2 during curtin installation
/dev/disk/by-uuid/2685d670-4f44-4739-84f8-6550f0a08e7b /boot ext4 defaults 0 1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during curtin installation
/dev/disk/by-uuid/872E-23CE /boot/efi vfat defaults 0 1
/swap.img   none    swap    sw  0   0
LABEL=SG_GREEN /media/jellyadmin/SG_GREEN auto     nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
LABEL=SG_Green_2 /media/jellyadmin/SG_Green_2 auto     nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
LABEL=WD_BLACK /media/jellyadmin/WD_BLACK auto     nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
jellyadmin@jellyfin-drake:/etc$ 

My User folder in /media
jellyadmin@jellyfin-drake:/media$ ls -l
total 8
drwxr-x---+ 5 root jellyfinmedia 4096 Jun 19 00:52 jellyadmin
drwxr-x---+ 2 root root          4096 Jun 19 00:43 root

And the containing folders that I can't chown:
jellyadmin@jellyfin-drake:/media/jellyadmin$ ls -l
total 1536
drwxr-xr-x 7 root root  262144 Jun 20 22:25 SG_GREEN
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root  262144 Jun 20 22:25 SG_Green_2
drwxr-xr-x 7 root root 1048576 Jun 20 22:17 WD_BLACK
jellyadmin@jellyfin-drake:/media/jellyadmin$ 


So yes you have messed up ownership/permissions of /mnt and /media - however that's unlikely to prevent the display manager from starting. Have you done the suggested See "systemctl status gdm.service" and "journalctl -xeu gdm.service" for details. ?

Added the output of those commands. Seems the generate-config error due to read-only file system might be part of the issue.

OK thanks so the output of findmnt -T /var/lib/gdm3 may be helpful

Added - So if I understand, the drive where the display manager is located was changed to read-only, and that's why it won't start?

Likely yes - and the findmnt output indicates it's your whole root filesystem / that's read-only (rather than a separate /var partition). So you need to diagnose and repair that - typically it's because the system has detected disk corruption and has remounted the filesystem ro to prevent further damage.

Posted my fstab file, df -h as well as the output when I try to remount the internal drive. every time I think I'm getting close, I end up lost again lol. I need to take a class on Linux permissions and disk management!

Your fstab is broken, I don't see a line for your /-filesystem but 2 identical lines for /boot/efi. We don't know in which way you messed around with permissions, so it is not possible to give proper advice how to fix. The mount on /var/snap/firefox/common/host-hunspell is snap related and readonly by default, nothing wrong with that. The missing line in fstab for your /-filesystem prevents boot.

... you most definitely don't want uid=1000,gid=1000 when remounting the root filesystem (I'm not sure if ext2/3/4 even support those options - or if they would be silently ignored)

@steeldriver This mount options seem to be invalid for ext# partitions. The mount on /var/snap/firefox/common/host-hunspell is snap related and read-only by default. See This answer. It doesn't seem to have anything to do with OP's problems.

Updated with the latest. I did a fresh install, then used the "Disks" app to make the 3 external drives auto mount. After doing that though, it now says "root" is the owner and I can't make any changes to the files/folders. I think I need to edit my fstab file so it mounts with the correct user and group, jellyadmin is the user and jellyfinmedia is the group.

Check if you have disk space enough. I had a similar issue on a virtual machine until I realized that the root partition was with no disk space, causing that in the boot process appear this error. Remove via terminal some files and reboot the machine work for me. Or try to resize the fully partition. If not is disk space issue this is not are going to work for you. Hope it helps.
